# Test whether two categorical questions are statistically different?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I have two questions (Q1, Q2) and they can be answered with either Yes or No.

I want to test if there is a significant difference between the answers to Q1 and Q2, because the questions are related to each other:

Q1 Do you current fulfill X tasks?

Q2 Are you interested in X tasks?

|  | Current? | Interest? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 10 | 15 |
| No | 20 | 15 |

I thought that I could use a Chi-squared test but I am not sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can arrange the counts for the two categories as you have above and test the hypothesis of independence with Pearson's chi-squared test of independence. In R, as follows:

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(10, 20, 15, 15), nrow = 2)

chisq.test(mat, correct = FALSE)
```

This produces a p-value of ~0.19, so there's not sufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis.